# Python Facebook Ads API call not going through

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to extract data from ads I am running from my facebook page into a csv and push it into a sql db.I am new to web development, and I am unsure whether I have to make a separate fb app and use the ads sdk in order to do this, or if i can just write a script,or if I am going in the right direction at all. The following block of code from the marketing api results in 'Api call cannot be made if api is not set')
facebookads.exceptions.FacebookBadObjectError: Api call cannot be made if api is not set. , at the first api call with async_job. Any links/tutorial would be appreciated as I am currently lost in documentation

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python

import urllib2
import json
from facebookads.adobjects.campaign import Campaign
from facebookads.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebookads.adobjects.adreportrun import AdReportRun
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads import objects
import time






campaign = Campaign(xxxxxxxxx)
params = {
 'level': AdsInsights.Level.campaign,
}
async_job = campaign.get_insights(params=params, async=True)

async_job.remote_read()

while async_job[AdReportRun.Field.async_percent_completion] < 100:
time.sleep(1)
async_job.remote_read()

time.sleep(1)

print(async_job.get_result())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python

import urllib2
import json
from facebookads.adobjects.campaign import Campaign
from facebookads.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebookads.adobjects.adreportrun import AdReportRun
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads import objects
import time

# init Facebook API
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi

FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token='your_access_token')




campaign = Campaign(xxxxxxxxx)
params = {
'level': AdsInsights.Level.campaign,
}
async_job = campaign.get_insights(params=params, async=True)

async_job.remote_read()

while async_job[AdReportRun.Field.async_percent_completion] < 100:
time.sleep(1)
async_job.remote_read()

time.sleep(1)

print(async_job.get_result())
```

The Facebook Doc is confuse.